# How does the Fighters possible bonus action from Action Surge work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter

I'm playing a Fighter in my friends new campaign and I recently leveled up and gained Action Surge. When I was reading it, it said

> On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and one possible bonus action.

It confused me when it said a possible bonus action and gave no example of when you could get a possible extra bonus action from Action Surge or if you're suppose to roll dice to determine whether or not you get the extra bonus action on top of your other bonus action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Action Surge doesn't affect Bonus Actions

Action surge gives you an additional Action, on top of the regular Action and bonus action you are allowed on each turn. The 'possible' in the rule is there because not every character may be allowed to use the bonus action. If you don't have any feature or ability that lets you use a bonus action, you can't.